# How can I resize Flash images on disk without affecting the way Flash displays them?

Tags: flash

I've got an animation in Flash that's made up of a number of large images. Too large, it turns out — Flash keeps running out of memory and crashing.

I'd like to scale the images down to 50% but maintain their on-stage size in Flash (or at least keep their positions the same). I've scaled them down on disk, but this scales them in Flash too (and therefore messes up their relationships).

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: The OP accidentally posted a copy of this question [here, on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498814/resizing-flash-images-on-disk-without-affecting-flash-stage). This message was originally in the question body, but I'm moving it here because it takes up a lot of the preview space.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than scale down their size, scale down their pixel depth instead.  If it's a "deep" image type such as BMP or TIFF, convert it to JPEG or PNG or GIF instead.  If you're already using JPEG, change the quality setting to a lower value.  This can greatly reduce the file size, without changing the on screen size of the images.